# how to add a new column in pre created dataset in aws quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

> I have a pre created dataset in aws quicksight. Now I want to add a column to this dataset by getting data from sql table. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

After alter your SQL table, open your quicksight dataset
Under "Query mode" choose refresh now
When refresh finished click on "Save & Publish"
Then you can see it on your analyses